# Population centroid of irregular-shaped German counties based on a population density grid

Tags: qgis, population, county, germany, center

I'm new to QGIS and stuck with this task. Here's the data I'm working with:

- 1-square-kilometer grid Shapefile of Germany (https://www.zensus2011.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/DE/Shapefile/Inspire.zip?__blob=publicationFile&v=5)
- Population Data for each kilometer-grid as CSV. Can be joined with the grid Shapefile with column "ID_1km". Column "Einwohner" represents population divided in 7 classes (-1 unknown, 0 to 6 with 6 being the highest population density) (https://www.zensus2011.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/DE/Pressemitteilung/DemografischeGrunddaten/csv_Zensusatlas_klassierte_Werte_1km_Gitter.zip?__blob=publicationFile&v=8)
- Germany's counties "Kreise" as Shapefile (VG250_Kreise.shp)(https://www.zensus2011.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/DE/Shapefile/VG250_1Jan2011_WGS84.zip?__blob=publicationFile&v=29)

The goal is to calculate the weighted population centroid for each county (image 1) based on the population density grid (image 2). In the end I want to export a list of the latitude/longitude coordinates of the centroids of all counties.
[image: Counties of Germany]
[image: Population Grid]

So far I was able to join the CSV data with the 1km-grid Shapefile. Then I've tried intersecting the two layers and playing around with the vector centroid function but nothing has worked. I have no clue how I can tackle this task and I couldn't find any solution online.

Comment: I found a few posts where a "weighted centroid" is also called a "weighted mean center" - apparently ArcGIS has a tool by that name. If these links don't help at least you might have more luck with the new search term. https://glenbambrick.com/tag/weighted-mean-center/ https://community.esri.com/thread/71165

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer would be "Try **Mean centroid(s)** in the *Processing Toolbox > Vector Analysis*".

However, your dataset needs to get pre-processed before applying the tool.

**(1) Pre-process** (this part is specific to your data)

- Let's assume you already have a **Joined layer** (**1**) by joining *1-square-kilometer grid* and *Population Data as CSV*.
- You would also have reprojected the *VG250_Kreise* county polygon (WGS84) to ETRS89 LAEA (named **VG250_1Jan2011_ETRS89_LAEA_Kreise** in my example **(2)**).
- Then the first step is to create a **Centroids (3)** layer, converted from your **Joined layer** (**1**) which was a polygon layer.
- Because the negative number (*-1 for unknown*) in your column "Einwohner" prevents to use it as the weight, we need to remove them using an expression (e.g. "Einwohner" > -1). In this example the output layername is **Centroids_without_negative (4)** .
- Now, you need to attach the County ID (**OBJECTID**) to the above processed centroids layer. A picture attached below shows the **Join attributes by location** tool, which takes **Centroids_without_negative (4)** and **VG250_1Jan2011_ETRS89_LAEA_Kreise (2)** as inputs, with **OBJECTID** as the *Field to add* (you can add all the fields if you like).

[image]

**(2) Main process**

The above pre-processing would have given a new **Joined layer** (shown as brown points in the image below).

Start **Mean coordinate(s)** tool and set options like below:

- Input layer: **Joined layer (5)**
- Weight field: **Column "Einwohner"**
- Unique ID field: **OBJECTID**

[image]

**(3) Output and caveat**

Click on <kbd>Run</kbd> button and you will see something like below:

[image]

- The result **Mean coordinate(s)** (*Weighted mean centroids*) generally looks OK (such as **(A)** at upper-right).
- However, you will find some centroids are not located within the polygon it should be in (see **(B)** at lower-right, pointed by a blue-arrow). These off-points would have to be processed separately.